# Connect to RabbitMQ via URL

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, easynetq

I'm trying to connect to the rabbitmq which is hidden behind nginx proxy. It's declared as:

```
   location ^~ /rabbitmq/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5672/;
   }
```

The problem is that as I found AMPQ only specifies host but it doesn't know anything about urls.

Can I connect rabbit client to `www.myserver.com/rabbitmq` somehow? I'm using EasyNetQ to connect, but it looks like a protocol limitation, and implementation doesn't matter.

If it's not possible at all maybe there are some workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

For `AMQP`, If using Nginx probably doing a TCP load balancing could help: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/, otherwise if you could use [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) you could try something like this:

```
frontend rabbitmq
    mode tcp
    bind *:5672
    use_backend bunny 

backend bunny
    mode tcp
    server bunny 127.0.0.1:5672 check
```

If you want to publish message over HTTP probably you would like to expose the rabbitmq API:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/index.html
```

Notice the port `15672`, from the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html):

> Note that the UI and HTTP API port — typically 15672 — does not support AMQP 0-9-1, AMQP 1.0, STOMP or MQTT connections. Separate ports should be used by those clients.